# Error:(61, 48) error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to List<BarEntry> in mpandroidchart

Tags: java, android, arraylist, mpandroidchart

there I am getting this error while showing the data from myTable.java.
Incompatible type is showing

```
BarChart chart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.datachart);

ArrayList<String> BarEntry = new ArrayList<>();

BarEntry.add(myTable.getPopulation_1980());

ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<>();
labels.add("1980");
labels.add("1985");
labels.add("1990");


BarDataSet bardataset = new BarDataSet(BarEntry, "Cells");
BarData data = new BarData(labels, bardataset);
chart.setData(data);
```

but it is showing error on `Bardataset bardataset = new Bardadtaset(BarEntry, "cells")`

please give me any suggestions

Comment: Same problem coming?

Comment: no... i am using a version 2.2.4 , but if you know , please post the answer so it would be helpful for others... I am having a different issue now. can you help me ..regarding mpandroidchart?

Answer (score 1):

> incompatible types: String cannot be converted to List in
>   mpandroidchart

```
 BarDataSet bardataset = new BarDataSet(BarEntry, "Cells");
```

> The constructor for BarData has changed in v3.0.0

Read [**`Setting Data`**](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Setting-Data).

```
public BarDataSet(List<BarEntry> yVals, String label) {
        super(yVals, label);

        ......
    }
```

Comment: no... still showing error because BarDataSET is from a mpchartandroid library ...thats y i have posted this question in SO

Comment: @Vivek Kindly read https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/2163